# Host PHP vs Docker PHP: 5 times slower

Tags: php, linux, docker, performance

we are using docker for PHP development and i was curious about performance differences when running PHP 7.4 on my host machine vs running code within a docker container.

I'm running recent `Linux Mint` version and the docker version is `Docker version 20.10.17` - without special non-standard configurations.

To get a fair comparison of both PHP environments i double checked the configuration and of course also disabled xdebug.

Then i run some basic php benchmark which i found on github:

```
<?php

$startTime = time();
$runSeconds = 5;
$rounds = 5;
$count = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<$rounds; $i++) {
    while ((time()-$startTime) <= $runSeconds) {
        serialize(['bar'=>'foo']);
        $count ++;
    }
    $round = $i+1;
    $startTime += $runSeconds;
    $count = number_format($count);
    echo "Round {$round}: {$count} /per {$runSeconds} second\n";
    $count = 0;
}
```

**The results on my host machine PHP 7.4:**

```
Round 1: 93,052,589 /per 5 second
Round 2: 89,096,400 /per 5 second
Round 3: 89,190,317 /per 5 second
Round 4: 89,145,362 /per 5 second
Round 5: 88,923,066 /per 5 second
```

**Docker PHP 7.4**

https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.4.30-zts-alpine3.15/images/sha256-6e1a13b9e0446eedc3a1220b24ed52727b3330a165b5787395c1a3082e355481?context=explore

```
Round 1: 18,937,581 /per 5 second
Round 2: 16,089,889 /per 5 second
Round 3: 16,083,545 /per 5 second
Round 4: 16,087,953 /per 5 second
Round 5: 16,079,214 /per 5 second
```

That's a HUGE difference. Are there some common bottlenecks which explains that huge differences?

I thought Docker didn't have much of an overhead, at least overhead that should be negligible - but 5 times slower performance is already a lot I think.

Comment: Alpine is an odd duck and frequently uses underlying libraries different from what most consider standard, eg: musl vs glibc. Alpine's goal is to have a small image footprint, and performance/convenience can take a backseat to that. Try the default Debian Bullseye image for a more fair comparison.

Comment: Quick comparison on my machine gets: Alpine: 19m, Bullseye: 28m, Native [old Ubuntu]: 30m

Comment: @Sammitch man this is already a huge difference, thx.  with bullseye i now get around 40m

Answer (score 7):

I can confirm that `Alpine` performed significantly slower on my machine using a very similar test.

Seem it could be related to different underlaying libraries and different kernel options (e.g. RAM huge pages are disabled and opcache won't benefit from it).

Comparison (higher is better aka. iterations count in 25s, opcache disabled):

```
OS 7.4.18 (current)             Total: 89,226,100
Custom 7.4.32 Alpine            Total: 57,472,042
Official 7.4.33 Bullseye        Total: 101,363,370
Official 8.1.15 Alpine          Total: 53,698,833
Official 8.1.15 Bullseye        Total: 103,377,353
Official 8.1.15 Bullseye+JIT    Total: 102,026,978
Official 7.4.33 Alpine          Total: 58,911,670
```

Test snippet:

```
...

for ($i = 0; $i < $rounds; $i++) {
    $startTime = time();
    while ((time() - $startTime) <= $runSeconds) {
        $prefix = (string)$count . '|' . (string)$i;
        json_encode([$prefix . 'bar' => $prefix . 'foo'], JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
        $count++;
    }

    $round = $i + 1;
    $startTime += $runSeconds;
    $total += $count;
    $count = number_format($count);

    echo " Round {$round}: {$count} per {$runSeconds} second\n";

    $count = 0;
}
echo " Total: " . number_format($total) . "\n";
```